# Explanation of colon operator in ": ${foo=value}"

Tags: bash

I understand the colon operator in bash that acts like [a null](http://devmanual.gentoo.org/tools-reference/bash/index.html#multiple-selection), and I know it's used in [parameter expansion](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_29.html), as well as being used other ways, but can someone explain this:

```
: ${SOMETHING='value'}
```

From experimentation I know that this sets the environment variable `$SOMETHING` to `'value'` but why?

"Just because it does" is a valid answer but then please point me to the documentation for it (which I can't seem to find) or a proper name for this usage would be useful. I'm hoping there's a more enlightening explanation though.

Comment: Note that the `:` built-in exists in bourne shell and ksh as well as bash.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The expression `${SOMETHING='value'}` sets SOMETHING to `value` if it isn't already set. This is a useful operator to have in many situations. However, it also returns the assigned value, so if you simply executed

```
${SOMETHING='value'}
```

then your shell would try to invoke the command `value`. This might or might not do something unwanted; at the least it would throw a message "value: command not found".

To avoid this you can use the no-op `:`, which evaluates its argument and then throws it away, rather than executing it. This is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).

Comment: The `:` builtin command is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).  It is also a [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#colon).

Comment: Also explained [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#COLON0REF).

Comment: is there any difference between : ${SOMETHING="$HMMM"} and : ${SOMETHING:="$HMMM"}  ? note second colon in the last example

Comment: @YuryKozlov The first variation (`=`) will use the default value if the parameter is `unset`; the latter (`:=`) will use the default if the parameter is `null` *or* `unset`

Answer (score 7):

Explained here : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

> If parameter not set, set it to default.
>
> Both forms nearly equivalent. The : makes a difference only when
>   $parameter has been declared and is null, [1] as above.
>
> ```
> echo ${var=abc}   # abc
> echo ${var=xyz}   # abc
> # $var had already been set to abc, so it did not change.
> ```

Comment: I'd suggest http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe or http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 (and its links) as better references than the ABS (which is chronically undermaintained and has a tendency to showcase bad practices in its examples).