# Setting EDITOR environment variable to colon (:) to no-op editor

Tags: git, unix, editor

Is setting the `EDITOR` environment variable to `:` to mean no-op supported behavior in Unix? Or is it special to Git?

I stumbled across this example of passing `EDITOR=:` to Git to short-circuit any attempt to launch an editor:

```
# Amend the commit, reusing the commit message
EDITOR=: git commit --amend
```

But hang on a sec. Why does that work? The `EDITOR` environment variable should be set to point to an editor executable in your `PATH`, like `EDITOR=vim` and such. After doing some digging, I've found that Git explicitly checks the editor value against `:` and does not launch an editor in that case. (See [commit.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1f66975deb8402131fbf7c14330d0c7cdebaeaa2/editor.c#L39-L61) for the gory details.)

So to get back to the question, it seems Git supports `:` as a no-op editor, and it does this by special-casing. Is `:` even a legal value for `EDITOR`, or something of a convention supported by some programs? (An alternative would be to set `EDITOR=echo` or `EDITOR=touch` so that the editor is invoked as `touch FILE`, leaving `FILE` unmodified.)

#### Bonus

Using `:` to mean no-op for `EDITOR` seems oddly similar to how the `:` Bash builtin is the no-op command equivalent to `true`. Coincidence?

[What is the use case of noop [:] in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404661/what-is-the-use-case-of-noop-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `:` is likely a nod to Bourne shells ([more reading on that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3224910/54249)), but as you note it is explicitly handled in Git. I don't know of anywhere documenting `EDITOR=:` as something that is expected to work globally.

Git support for `EDITOR=:` dates all the way back to 2007: https://github.com/git/git/commit/943316e96ca2dad67086af2f945e42467a27ddd6!