# Explain this shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Autoconf documentation recommends this snippet for portability:

```
      # Create a temporary directory $tmp in $TMPDIR (default /tmp).
      # Use mktemp if possible; otherwise fall back on mkdir,
      # with $RANDOM to make collisions less likely.
      : ${TMPDIR=/tmp}
      {
        tmp=`
          (umask 077 && mktemp -d "$TMPDIR/fooXXXXXX") 2>/dev/null
        ` &&
        test -n "$tmp" && test -d "$tmp"
      } || {
        tmp=$TMPDIR/foo$$-$RANDOM

        (umask 077 && mkdir "$tmp")
      } || exit $?
```

I don’t understand the first line:

Why does it begin with a `:`?

Why is the `TMPDIR` variable used just after that?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this other [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444504/explanation-of-this-use-of-the-colon-operator) :)

Answer (score 2):

: ${TMPDIR=/tmp}  means:

: is null command in bash , but shell assign /tmp  to TMPDIR variable if content of TMPDIR is null

Answer (score 0):

The ": ${TMPDIR=/tmp}" line is invoking [":" shell built-in](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html), which does nothing, with a single argument - result of "${TMPDIR=/tmp}" [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

This parameter expansion assigns "/tmp" to TMPDIR variable, if it was unset (not set to anything before, even empty string), and then expands to the value of TMPDIR, which is ignored by ":" builtin.