# Shell Script check for no input and set the variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have trouble with a bash script. I want the user to state the username and if not set, set it automatically to root.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "MySQL User: (root)"
read MYSQLUSER
if [[ "$MYSQLUSER" == "" ]]; then
    set MYSQLUSER = "root"
fi
```

I've tried various syntaxes and shells but the if statement is always being ignored. This should be run on a Mac. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That `if` statement is fine. Your `set` line is incorrect though. That's not a bash variable assignment. You want `MYSQLUSER=root` there. But there are other ways to do this too. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7444504/258523 for a question about a standard idiom for this usage.

Comment: Also, the `-z` option checks for zero length.  `if [[ -z "$MYSQLUSER" ]]` would work just as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
your_var=${MYSQLUSER:-root}
```

The `${var:-$DEFAULT}` means: *If var not set or is empty, evaluate expression as $DEFAULT **.

---

All together, I would rewrite the script to something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "MySQL User: (root) "
read MYSQLUSER
MYSQLUSER=${MYSQLUSER:-root}
echo "mysqluser: $MYSQLUSER"
```

See its execution with different behaviours:

```
$ ./a.sh 
MySQL User: (root)              #just pressed intro
mysqluser: root
$ ./a.sh 
MySQL User: (root) hello        #I wrote 'hello'
mysqluser: hello
```

Comment: Do you know what the difference between `{:-}` and `{:=}` is ?

Comment: It is either a normal-person smiley or a big-nose one :D Also, from http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html the one with `=` has some extra condition: _Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to in this way._

Comment: Pretty crooked smile as well :) The link goes to a 404 though!

Comment: Uhms there was a trailing comma, fixed @JID !

Comment: Fedorqui, i Realised the difference, not sure it's what you said. It appears `${var:-$new}` uses new instead of var for whatever command called it but var would remain empty whereas `${var:=$new}` would make var equal to new permanently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain it a bit more how this can be implemented into my script. i don't fully understand how to apply your example to my code sample. Is my assumption correct, that I simply remove the if statement and whenever I use the $MYSQLUSER in my script var i'd just replace it with ${MYSQLUSER:-root} ?

Comment: @JID I guess that fedorqui's point is a consequence of the fact that `${var:=$new}` assigns to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom is to use the command

```
: ${MYSQLUSR:=root}
```

which assigns the value `root` to `MYSQLUSER` if it does not already have a non-null value.

(`:` is the do-nothing command; the arguments are evaluated, then ignored. It's the evaluation of the `:=` expansion that actually sets the value of `MYSQLUSER`.)